# how to include python pex package in yocto image

Tags: python, pip, yocto, pypi, pex

I need to include python pex package into my yocto image.

I tried to use setupautotools and pypi package, it did not provide results.

The python pex is not available as pypi package.

Can someone help including python pex into my yocto image.

Link for pex: https://pypi.org/project/pex/#description

Is there any way to install pex without pip?

Updated question:
I need to install pex package mentioned in the link into my yocto image. 
The pex package is not available in git repository like wheel https://github.com/pypa/wheel. 
Due to this reason i am not able to use "inherit pypi setuptools" in .bb files in yocto recipe.

Comment: What do you mean by "The python pex is not available as pypi package." ?? You posted the link to the pypi pex package

Comment: @FlorianBerndl updated the question with requested details. Please let me know your comments on this one.

Comment: https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex is the github repo, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pex is the pypi package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything you need to write as the other python package are already there.

https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex is the github repo

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pex is the pypi package

You need something similar to:

```
SUMMARY = "pex is a library for generating .pex (Python EXecutable) files which are executable Python environments in the spirit of virtualenvs."
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex"
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = ""
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=0123"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "0123"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "0123"

PYPI_PACKAGE="pex"

inherit pypi 

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "\
    ${PYTHON_PN}-core \
"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

Comment: Facing below issue:
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| ERROR: python setup.py build execution failed.
| /export01/knt8cob/release/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/pex/2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python-native/python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: The bb file used is below
SECTION = "devel/python"
#LICENSE = ""
#LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=0123"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex.git;branch=master"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "55e3fe4ff51a538eb182c9c84b83eff2"

#PYPI_PACKAGE="pex"
DEPENDS = "python-setuptools"
inherit setuptools pythonnative

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"

LICENSE="CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM=""

Comment: this package has no setuptools. please try my recipe

Comment: After trying your recipe it got compiled but nothing available in image. Yocto says package not found.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and recipe file. It helped me a lot with solving the issue. I could found the issue with master branch of the git repository. The setup.py file is empty in master branch. This may be caused the issue. It worked for me after changing the version.